# цикл while с input()

Tags: python

я хочу написать цикл, который позволяет вводить число, до тех пор, пока оно не станет равно 12, в чём ошибка? Само число можно ввести только 1 раз, после этого программа завершается.

```
a=0
while a<10:
    b = int(input())
    a=a+1
    print(b)
    if b==12:
        print('breaking')
    break
```

Comment: Какое число надо чтобы было 12, а или б? Не стоит ли поменять на `a += 1`?

Comment: @entithat, это всё, что тебя смущает?

Comment: Да и так заново напишу @Qwertiy. "До тех пор, пока оно не станет равно 12, - звучит как `while True`, а не `a < 10`

Comment: @entithat, да, это место не заметил.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В том, что `break` не с тем отступом.

А ещё, как заметил [@entithat](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/272305/entithat), у `while` условие неверное.